# how to found out if a custom hook_cron has been run?

Tags: cron

what is the best way to find out if a custom hook_cron which runs automatically , has been run?
I did use drupal_set_message and watchdog but they weren't suitable for automatic crons.

Comment: What wasn't suitable about using `watchdog()`? That's how Drupal core communicates that a cron has been run; whether it was 'automatic' or not is completely incidental, the code will fire either way

Comment: the database loging module is disable and the table has many records. is there a way to clear it without refering to mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Cron runs, it leaves a message in the next table: Reports -> Recent log messages.

If you want to know if a specefic hook has been run, you could try an experiment. For example, you could create a variable called module_variable with value 0 in your  database table and increment this value each time the hook is run.

Comment: tanx a lot, I'm going to use variables. nice solution